# ExtJS 6: multiple locale files for the same language

Tags: javascript, extjs, localization

I'm using the [locale-package](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/localization.html) from ExtJS(6.2) for my application and I'm curious if there is a way to create multiple locale files for the same language.

For now I have 2 locale files: `myapp-locale-de.js` and `myapp-locale-en.js`, but those are getting way to big and I want to split them up into multiple files:

- myapp-locale-de-core.js
- myapp-locale-de-main.js
- myapp-locale-de-misc.js

and merge them in a specific order together to create one final locale file.
Is there any ext-magic or maybe even an easier solution to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the OOTB configuration offers that level of flexibility, but there's a [blog post here](https://www.sencha.com/blog/internationalization-localization-with-sencha-ext-js/) which talks about alternate options for manually resolving language files - with examples that could be easily modified to suit your specific requirement.

Comment: Hey! I just realized that I don't need to set a specific order. I added the files I mentioned above and they're all getting loaded into my application.
Thank you anyway. =)